# How many magic bottles are there and where can I find them?

Tags: zelda-link-to-the-past

I am playing *The Legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past* and I was wondering how many magic bottles you can get in total - I have three already but there looks like there is space for a fourth one?

I have completed the game many times and have never found more than three.

Is there a fourth magic bottle and where can I get it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are four magic bottles in *A Link to the Past*; you haven't said which ones you've found so here are the locations of all of them:

- You get the first one by buying it for 100 rupees from a bottle merchant in Kakariko Village (near the statue)
- There is another located in the back of the bar in Kakariko, you must enter through the back entrance, which is not visible from the outside (just walk into the top of the building in the middle)
- Once you have Zora's Flippers, you will find another under the stone bridge near Lake Hylia. Talk to the guy that is asleep under the bridge and he will give it to you.
- There is a blue chest inside the Dwarven sword-smith's home while in the dark world, take the chest to the "average guy" in the Desert of Mystery in the light world and promise not to tell anybody he is a thief. He will open the chest and give you the bottle. (Note: you need the Titan Mitts to access this area)

This video shows the locations of each of the magic bottles:

Comment: @perspektiv - which one are you missing? :-)

Comment: Having done a sword-less run, I'm pretty sure you don't need a tempered sword to get the fourth bottle. Just the Titan Mitts. I will admit it has been a while but I'm pretty sure I had all four bottles, I will have to check again later. Unless you're saying that the chest is just not there without the sword.

Comment: You are right, I think I put tempered sword because the dwarven hut is where that happens